# Using conditions to write to new row on new sheet to return value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I would like to be able to use a data-entry page or form to keep track of monthly fulfillment of orders.  We have some number of SKUs, lets say 10, and various number of orders against each SKU.  Production completes a non-uniform amount of one to all SKU(s) each day and posting of production can happen at anytime, more than once, on any day (24/7).

If the SKUs were listed in column A, the total order in column B and I (or a production operator) posted current production in column C, I would like column D to return the amount of orders remaining (thus all previously entered production on that SKU being kept (with date and time) on a different sheet and being continuously summed.)

```
SKU    Total Order   Current Production    Remaining Production
A       15,000         100                     15,000 -(100+ previous production of A)
B       2,000          0                       2,000 - (previous production of B)
C       7,500          3,000                   7,500 - (3,000 + previous production C)
```

Thanks for any help. The data entry sheet (or form) is important due to the number of SKUs we have (more than 10) and the number and excel-proficiency of people entering the data.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is well suited to a VBA solution. In my test workbook, I set up two worksheets along the lines you suggested.

The first is the summary worksheet, which would serve as the data entry form. The current production amounts for one or several SKUs would be entered in the highlighted area in column C, as shown in the screen shot below. (I am assuming that the only other hand-entered items would be the the total monthly orders for each SKU.)

The production amounts would be posted programmatically to a detail worksheet, and would in turn be summarized as "previous production" in the summary table of the first worksheet.

The posting to the detail would be triggered by a command button on the summary worksheet. When this button is pressed, each amount in the current production column of the summary worksheet would be copied to the detail sheet, along with the affected SKU and the current date and time. After the copying, the current production column of the summary sheet would be cleared.

The command button would be created from the Developer tab of the ribbon by inserting a button form into the summary sheet. Then the code would be linked to the button by choosing Design Mode, right-clicking on the button and selecting View Code, and pasting the code into the edit panel that comes up.

Since this process is a bit involved, I've made my test workbook available via [this Dropbox link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48805010/postProduction.xlsm).

### Summary worksheet

[image: Summary worksheet]

### Detail worksheet

[image: Detail worksheet]

### Command button code

```
  Option Explicit

  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

     Dim skuArr As Variant
     Dim prodArr As Variant
     Dim postRow As Long
     Dim currDate As Long
     Dim currTime As Double
     Dim i As Long

     'turn off background processes
     With Excel.Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
     End With

     'put SKUs and current production amounts into arrays
     skuArr = Range("Summary!SKUS").Value
     prodArr = Range("Summary!CurrentProd").Value

     'find first empty row of detail worksheet
     postRow = 1 + Worksheets("Detail").Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

     'save date and time
     currDate = Range("Summary!CurrentDate").Value
     currTime = Range("Summary!CurrentTime").Value

     With Worksheets("Detail")

        'write date, time, SKU, and new prod amount to detail sheet
        'cell formatting lines can be eliminated if Detail sheet is preformatted
        For i = LBound(skuArr, 1) To UBound(skuArr, 1)
           If Not (prodArr(i, 1) = "") Then
              .Cells(postRow, 1).Value = currDate
              .Cells(postRow, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
              .Cells(postRow, 2).Value = currTime
              .Cells(postRow, 2).NumberFormat = "HH:MM"
              .Cells(postRow, 3).Value = skuArr(i, 1)
              .Cells(postRow, 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
              .Cells(postRow, 4).Value = prodArr(i, 1)
              postRow = postRow + 1
           End If
        Next i
     End With

     'Clear posted amounts from summary sheet
     Range("Summary!CurrentProd").Value = ""

     With Excel.Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
     End With

  End Sub
```

Comment: This is fantastic.  Thanks so much for the detailed instruction and the link to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help. You can show others that this answer solved your problem by accepting the answer (clicking the check mark). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a PivotTable to sum the total production and link the SKU totals from there into the ColumnD first sheet formula:

[image: SU593676 example]

But this does not attempt to address what should happen when an order is complete.